# Using @property without getter / setter

Tags: python

Looking through pandas code, I see a lot of this construct :

```
@property
def _constructor(self):
    return Series
```

and then it is called like in :

```
def view(self, dtype=None):
    return self._constructor(self._values.view(dtype),
                             index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
```

What is the `@property` decorator used for here? And more generally, when would you use `@property` without getter or setter?

Comment: What do you mean without a getter? That *is* the getter. The decorator is used to make it attribute access `self._constructor` rather than a method call `self._constructor()`.

Comment: yes that's right, I meant without using both. Is using `self._constructor` instead of `self._constructor()` only more elegant (to avoid repetition of parentheses?), or does it serve another purpose?

Comment: @graham yeah, I'd guess the goal is to avoid this ugliness: `self._constructor()()`